# iOS (iPhone/iPad): downloading a big PDF via Safari doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, http, pdf

I've a small site designed to sell a HTTP-downloadable, ~300 MB PDF, No-DRM, page-scanned images e-book (download the test copy here http://test.magicmedicine.eu/get/ac123457965d0d4b4d17557a73cf2fe8 ).

It works flawlessly on PC, Mac and Android, but I'm experiencing issues with iOS: when the customer opens (I tried via broadband Wi-Fi+DSL) the download URL via Safari, the page loads for ~45 seconds (the page is blank but the activity indicator rotates), then Safari exits with no error messages at all.

I tried to create the PDF with the "Fast web view" (=progressive download) attribute and I also lowered the compatibility to the minimum (PDF version 1.3), with no results.

Application-side, the download is sent from Apache+PHP via mod_xsendfile ( https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ ) to the client with the following headers (my intent is to avoid the PDF-in-the-browser-via-plugin view):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 May 2012 09:50:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Expires: Thu, 24 May 2012 11:50:13 +0200
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: public
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="book.pdf"
Last-Modified: Sun, 20 May 2012 11:26:54 GMT
ETag: "2e01b4-dde8a9b-4c07610070008"
Content-Length: 232688283
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Any ideas?

Note: I asked this on SuperUser a couple of days ago and was closed as "off topic". I hope here it's ok to repost it here.

Comment: I hope you get some good answers but in any case you should consider reporting a bug to Apple. If you have developer id you can do it here: https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/bugrptform.html

Comment: This is a bug in the iPad. I have had PDFs, which are 30MB in size, crash on opening. I assume that they are taking up too much RAM to render and the operating system is terminating them to free memory.

This is on an iPad 1 and reading PDFs from Dropbox. Not exactly the same but its easy to see how an image intensive PDF could fail to open on a low memory device.